# how to control the permission in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Hi:
In my application,all the content in the site is only open for login user,that's to say if I have the following pages:

```
Default.aspx
Document.aspx
xxx.aspx
....
SysConfig.aspx
```

of course there is a login page:`login.aspx`.

All the pages exclude the "**login.aspx**" are protected,only login user can see them,and the **SysConfig.aspx** is just open for the user whose type is "admin".

So how to control this?

For example,when a user login  from the login.aspx,I can save the related information to the "Session",then in the "Default.aspx.cs" I can use:

```
if(Session["user"]==null).....
```

But if so ,I have to write the same codes in each protected page(the Document.aspx.cs/xxx.aspx.cs),I wonder if there is a easy way?

In java,I can make it simply use the struts2's interceptor,but I have no idea how to make it in asp.net.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your web.config file in the `system.web` section:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

This will prevent any unauthenticated users from to access your files.

And for your Admin user set access to `SysConfig`

```
<location path="SysConfig.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
            <allow roles="Admin"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

**Edit:** To allow access to login.aspx to an anonymous user, add this:

```
<location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>            
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
will protect unauthenticated user to access my files,but how about the login.aspx,it should be accessed by all user. BTW,after these settings,is there anything to do? for example,what should be done after a user login?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. After you reply I serach "asp.net user authorization",then I checked this post:http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/user-based-authorization-vb.     However I am not sure what does the "user" in the web.config mean,I do not think this "user" is the the "user" model in my app(I mean the users which will be saved to the database)