# How to deny access to folder or file

Tags: asp.net, permissions

I have an ASP.NET website and I need to block a specific folder named /swf.

This folder have a lot of swf files that cannot be accessed from unauthenticated users.

Ideas?

Comment: What are you using for authentication and role management?  Are you using standard Forms based authentication?

Comment: Have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685114/how-to-control-the-permission-in-asp-net/5685151#5685151

Comment: People, Forms authentication doesn't work in this case. It works to pages like site.com/swf/page.aspx. BUT doesn't work to images or swf files like site.com/swf/image.gif. I found the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582701/how-to-secure-access-to-swf-file-using-asp-net

Answer (score 10):

Consider using the `configuration/location` nodes in your web.config. Details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx)

```
<configuration>
    <location path="MySubDirectory">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="*"/> <!-- Denies all users -->
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was going to put once he answered my question above.  You beat me to it.  Good for you and +1.

Comment: I've seen this answer so many times, but for some reason it does absolutely nothing for me.

Comment: @deebs Same. I see this answer everywhere and not once has it ever actually denied public access to a file or folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options explained here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815151

Also, if you haven't already, I strongly recommend reading up on ASP.NET Authentication here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx

*Edit*

Since you're using Forms authentication and want to deny anonymous users, then you can create a web.confic in the swf folder and put the following in the authorization section:

```
<authorization>
     <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```