# How to deny access to folder in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to deny access to folder in asp.net server, i put this web.config file inside the folder and still, I have access to filed in it, what shoul I do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users ="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Other problem that I had is to create new directory inside the folder I am trying to deny using the server dynamicly, how to do it? There is a way create a folder in asp.net server without ftp? I tried to use

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~") + "newFolder");
```

but without success..

Comment: When compile path names, you should always use `Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "newFolder")`. This handles the trailing/non-trainling slashes.

Comment: The access part of your question is duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706553/how-to-deny-access-to-folder-or-file

Answer (score 1):

To deny access you can add this to the web.config file in your main folder:

```
<location path="folder_name_goes_here">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="admin_1"/>
      <allow users="admin_2"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>      
</location>
```

To create a folder try to add "\" between the MapPath and your folder :

```
 Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~") + "\\newFolder");
```

Comment: How to authorize myself as "admin_1"? Where I config my passwords?

Comment: @SagiGamil, From your login page, where you authenticate your users, after you checked their user name and password you send the user using 

System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(user_name, false);

You can find more details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user(v=vs.110).aspx